# How do I write custom action DLL for use in an MSI?

Tags: delphi, windows-installer, custom-action

This is a question I intend to answer myself, but please feel free to add other ways to accomplish this.

I was packaging an application for use on a wide variety of configurations, and I determined that the most reliable way to perform custom logic within my MSI would be to write my own custom action DLL that would be able to read/write from the PROPERTY table, kill a process, determine if an application needed to be upgraded (and then record the answer in the PROPERTY table), and write to the standard MSI log.

Comment: Another good, but older, solution for custom actions written in Delphi: http://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?124840-A-primer-on-custom-actions-written-in-Delphi

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My solution is in Delphi, and requires the open-source JEDI API translations that you can [download here](http://sourceforge.net/project/platformdownload.php?group_id=121894). One problem that I have found is that examples for using the JwaMSI headers are few and far between. Hopefully someone will find this as a useful example.

Here is the main unit, with a 2nd supporting unit following it (that you can include in the same DLL project). Simply create a new DLL (library) in Delphi, and copy/paste this code. This unit exports 2 functions that are callable from the MSI. They are:

1. CheckIfUpgradeable
2. KillRunningApp

Both of these functions read a PROPERTY value from the property table, and set a value when the complete. The idea is that then a 2nd custom action can read this property and throw an error, or use it as an install condition.

This code is more for an example, and in this example below it is checking to see if the version of 'notepad.exe' needs to be upgraded (that means the version stored in the property table value "NOTEPAD_VERSON" is greater than the version of notepad.exe on the system). If it is not, then it sets the property of "UPGRADEABLE_VERSION" to "NO" (this property is set to "YES" by default).

This code also looks in the PROPERTY table for "PROGRAM_TO_KILL" and will kill that program if it is running. It needs to include the file extension of the program to kill, e.g. "Notepad.exe"

```
library MsiHelper;

uses
  Windows,
  SysUtils,
  Classes,
  StrUtils,
  jwaMSI,
  jwaMSIDefs,
  jwaMSIQuery,
  JclSysInfo,
  PsApi,
  MSILogging in 'MSILogging.pas';

{$R *.res}


function CompareVersionNumbers(AVersion1, AVersion2: string): Integer;
var
  N1, N2: Integer;
//Returns 1 if AVersion1 < AVersion2
//Returns -1 if AVersion1 > AVersion2
//Returns 0 if values are equal
  function GetNextNumber(var Version: string): Integer;
  var
    P: Integer;
    S: string;
  begin
    P := Pos('.', Version);
    if P > 0 then
    begin
      S := Copy(Version, 1, P - 1);
      Version := Copy(Version, P + 1, Length(Version) - P);
    end
    else
    begin
      S := Version;
      Version := '';
    end;
    if S = '' then
      Result := -1
    else
    try
      Result := StrToInt(S);
    except
      Result := -1;
    end;
  end;

begin
  Result := 0;
  repeat
    N1 := GetNextNumber(AVersion1);
    N2 := GetNextNumber(AVersion2);
    if N2 > N1 then
    begin
      Result := 1;
      Exit;
    end
    else
    if N2 < N1 then
    begin
      Result := -1;
      Exit;
    end
  until (AVersion1 = '') and (AVersion2 = '');
end;

function GetFmtFileVersion(const FileName: String = ''; const Fmt: String = '%d.%d.%d.%d'): String;
var
  sFileName: String;
  iBufferSize: DWORD;
  iDummy: DWORD;
  pBuffer: Pointer;
  pFileInfo: Pointer;
  iVer: array[1..4] of Word;
begin
  // set default value
  Result := '';
  // get filename of exe/dll if no filename is specified
  sFileName := FileName;
  if (sFileName = '') then
  begin
    // prepare buffer for path and terminating #0
    SetLength(sFileName, MAX_PATH + 1);
    SetLength(sFileName,
      GetModuleFileName(hInstance, PChar(sFileName), MAX_PATH + 1));
  end;
  // get size of version info (0 if no version info exists)
  iBufferSize := GetFileVersionInfoSize(PChar(sFileName), iDummy);
  if (iBufferSize > 0) then
  begin
    GetMem(pBuffer, iBufferSize);
    try
    // get fixed file info (language independent)
    GetFileVersionInfo(PChar(sFileName), 0, iBufferSize, pBuffer);
    VerQueryValue(pBuffer, '\', pFileInfo, iDummy);
    // read version blocks
    iVer[1] := HiWord(PVSFixedFileInfo(pFileInfo)^.dwFileVersionMS);
    iVer[2] := LoWord(PVSFixedFileInfo(pFileInfo)^.dwFileVersionMS);
    iVer[3] := HiWord(PVSFixedFileInfo(pFileInfo)^.dwFileVersionLS);
    iVer[4] := LoWord(PVSFixedFileInfo(pFileInfo)^.dwFileVersionLS);
    finally
      FreeMem(pBuffer);
    end;
    // format result string
    Result := Format(Fmt, [iVer[1], iVer[2], iVer[3], iVer[4]]);
  end;
end;


function KillRunningApp(hInstall: MSIHandle): Integer; stdcall;
var
  aProcesses: array[0..1023] of DWORD;
  cbNeeded: DWORD;
  cProcesses: DWORD;
  i:    integer;
  szProcessName: array[0..MAX_PATH - 1] of char;
  hProcess: THandle;
  hMod: HModule;
  sProcessName : PChar;
  iProcessNameLength : Cardinal;
begin
  iProcessNameLength := MAX_PATH;
  sProcessName := StrAlloc(MAX_PATH);

  try
    //reads the value from "PROGRAM_TO_KILL" that is stored in the PROPERTY table
    MsiGetProperty(hInstall, 'PROGRAM_TO_KILL', sProcessName, iProcessNameLength);

    if not EnumProcesses(@aProcesses, sizeof(aProcesses), cbNeeded) then
    begin
      Exit;
    end;
    cProcesses := cbNeeded div sizeof(DWORD);

    for i := 0 to cProcesses - 1 do
    begin
      hProcess := OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION or PROCESS_VM_READ or PROCESS_TERMINATE, False, aProcesses[i]);
      try
      if hProcess <> 0 then
      begin
        if EnumProcessModules(hProcess, @hMod, sizeof(hMod), cbNeeded) then
        begin
          GetModuleBaseName(hProcess, hMod, szProcessName, sizeof(szProcessName));
          if UpperCase(szProcessName) = UpperCase(sProcessName) then
          begin
            TerminateProcess(hProcess, 0);
          end;
        end;
      end;
      finally
        CloseHandle(hProcess);
      end;                      
    end;
  finally
    StrDispose(sProcessName);
  end;

  Result:= ERROR_SUCCESS; //return success regardless of actual outcome
end;


function CheckIfUpgradeable(hInstall: MSIHandle): Integer; stdcall;
var
  Current_Notepad_version : PChar;
  Current_Notepad_version_Length  : Cardinal;
  sWinDir, sProgramFiles : string;
  bUpgradeableVersion : boolean;
  iNotepad_compare  : integer;
  sNotepad_version  : string;
  sNotepad_Location  : string;
  iResult : Cardinal;
begin
  bUpgradeableVersion := False;
  sWinDir := ExcludeTrailingBackslash(JclSysInfo.GetWindowsFolder);
  sProgramFiles := ExcludeTrailingBackslash(JclSysInfo.GetProgramFilesFolder);

  Current_Notepad_version_Length := MAX_PATH;
  Current_Notepad_version := StrAlloc(MAX_PATH);

  sNotepad_Location := sWinDir+'\system32\Notepad.exe';

  iResult := ERROR_SUCCESS;

  try
    //reads the value from "NOTEPAD_VERSION" that is stored in the PROPERTY table
    MsiGetProperty(hInstall, 'NOTEPAD_VERSION', Current_Notepad_version, Current_Notepad_version_Length);

    if Not (FileExists(sNotepad_Location)) then
    begin
      bUpgradeableVersion := True;
      LogString(hInstall,'Notepad.exe was not found at: "'+sNotepad_Location+'"');
      LogString(hInstall,'This version will be upgraded.');
      iResult := ERROR_SUCCESS;
      Exit;
    end;

    sNotepad_version := GetFmtFileVersion(sNotepad_Location);
    LogString(hInstall,'Found Notepad version="'+sNotepad_version+'"');  
    iNotepad_compare := CompareVersionNumbers(sNotepad_version,StrPas(Current_Notepad_version));

    if (iNotepad_compare < 0) then
    begin
      bUpgradeableVersion := False;
    end
    else
    begin
      bUpgradeableVersion := True;
    end;


    if bUpgradeableVersion then
    begin
      LogString(hInstall,'This version will be upgraded.');
      iResult := ERROR_SUCCESS;
    end
    else
    begin
      MsiSetProperty(hInstall,'UPGRADEABLE_VERSION','NO'); //this indicates failure -- this value is read by another custom action executed after this action
      LogString(hInstall,'ERROR: A newer version of this software is already installed. Setup cannot continue!');
      iResult := ERROR_SUCCESS;
    end;
  finally
    StrDispose(Current_Notepad_version);
  end;

  Result:= iResult; //this function always returns success, however it could return any of the values listed below
//
//Custom Action Return Values
//================================
//
//Return value                        Description
//
//ERROR_FUNCTION_NOT_CALLED           Action not executed.
//ERROR_SUCCESS                       Completed actions successfully.
//ERROR_INSTALL_USEREXIT              User terminated prematurely.
//ERROR_INSTALL_FAILURE               Unrecoverable error occurred.
//ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS                 Skip remaining actions, not an error.
//
end;

exports CheckIfUpgradeable;
exports KillRunningApp;

begin
end.
```

And here is the supporting unit "MSILogging.pas". This unit can be used as-is in other MSI DLL projects.

```
unit MSILogging;

interface

uses
  Windows,
  SysUtils,
  JwaMsi,
  JwaMsiQuery,
  JwaMSIDefs;

procedure LogString(hInstall: MSIHandle; sMsgString : string);
function MsiMessageBox(hInstall: MSIHandle; sMsgString : string; dwDlgFlags : integer): integer; 

implementation

procedure LogString(hInstall: MSIHandle; sMsgString : string);
var
  hNewMsiHandle : MSIHandle;
begin
  try
    hNewMsiHandle := MsiCreateRecord(2);

    sMsgString := '-- MSI_LOGGING -- ' + sMsgString;
    MsiRecordSetString(hNewMsiHandle, 0, PChar(sMsgString) );
    MsiProcessMessage(hInstall, INSTALLMESSAGE(INSTALLMESSAGE_INFO), hNewMsiHandle);
  finally
    MsiCloseHandle(hNewMsiHandle);
  end;
end;


function MsiMessageBox(hInstall: MSIHandle; sMsgString : string; dwDlgFlags : integer): integer;
var
  hNewMsiHandle : MSIHandle;
begin
  try
    hNewMsiHandle := MsiCreateRecord(2);
    MsiRecordSetString(hNewMsiHandle, 0, PChar(sMsgString) );
  finally
    MsiCloseHandle(hNewMsiHandle);
  end;

  //Result := (MsiProcessMessage(hInstall, INSTALLMESSAGE(dwDlgFlags), hNewMsiHandle));
    Result := (MsiProcessMessage(hInstall, INSTALLMESSAGE(INSTALLMESSAGE_USER + dwDlgFlags), hNewMsiHandle));
end;

end.
```

Comment: Note that for any function you want to be callable from your MSI, you must include "stdcall;" after it's prototype. Also, you must include a line somewhere that says "exports function_name".