# Understanding session information from WTSEnumerateSessions

Tags: winapi

I've been trying to use WTSEnumerateSessions to determine how many users are currently logged on, as suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368651/detecting-multiple-logged-on-users-via-win32).

My main problem is not understanding how to use the contents of the `WTS_SESSION_INFO` struct returned to determine how many users are logged on. In Windows XP Pro SP3, when a single user is logged on, I get two lots of session info;

Win Station Name: console,    ID: 0
Win Station Name: RDP-Tcp,    ID: 65536

In Windows 7 Ultimate (64 bit), again when a single user is logged on, I get two lots of session info:

Win Station Name: services,    ID: 0
Win Station Name: console,    ID: 1

Can anyone explain/point me in the direction of a resource that can explain how and why the session information differs between the two operating systems? And how can I determine how many users are logged on from this information?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why session 0 has changed: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756986.aspx

The RDP-Tcp session with ID 65536 is a listening session -- it just listens for incoming connections.

To determine how many users are logged on, I would suggest counting the number of sessions with nonempty usernames. You can fetch a session's username using [WTSQuerySessionInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383838(VS.85).aspx). If you are using a .NET language, you might find the [Cassia library](http://code.google.com/p/cassia/) more convenient to use.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use this to get info on the logged in users, consider using [WTSEnumerateSessionsEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee621014%28VS.85%29.aspx), as it has some useful extra fields, including `pUserName` and `pDomainName`.

I think it's less trouble that a combo of `WTSEnumerateSessions` and `WTSQuerySessionInformation`.

Comment: Unfortunately `WTSEnumerateSessionsEx` is available only in Windows 7 and above.