# C++ Get Username From Process

Tags: c++, winapi, process

I have a process handle with

```
HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, 0, THE_PROCESS_ID);
```

How can I get the username of the user that is running the process?

I am using unmanaged code (no .NET).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use [OpenProcessToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379295%28VS.85%29.aspx) to get the token (obviously), then [GetTokenInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446671%28VS.85%29.aspx) with the `TokenOwner` flag to get the SID of the owner. Then you can use [LookupAccountSid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379166%28VS.85%29.aspx) to get the username.

Comment: Worked great. I had to use TokenUser instead to get the user name. TokenOwner was returning the group name(Administrators).

Answer (score 9):

if WMI is not an option, then use **GetUserFromProcess** below that takes the process ID as an input parameter and returns the user name and domain:

```
#include <comdef.h>
#define MAX_NAME 256
BOOL GetLogonFromToken (HANDLE hToken, _bstr_t& strUser, _bstr_t& strdomain) 
{
   DWORD dwSize = MAX_NAME;
   BOOL bSuccess = FALSE;
   DWORD dwLength = 0;
   strUser = "";
   strdomain = "";
   PTOKEN_USER ptu = NULL;
 //Verify the parameter passed in is not NULL.
    if (NULL == hToken)
        goto Cleanup;

       if (!GetTokenInformation(
         hToken,         // handle to the access token
         TokenUser,    // get information about the token's groups 
         (LPVOID) ptu,   // pointer to PTOKEN_USER buffer
         0,              // size of buffer
         &dwLength       // receives required buffer size
      )) 
   {
      if (GetLastError() != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) 
         goto Cleanup;

      ptu = (PTOKEN_USER)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(),
         HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, dwLength);

      if (ptu == NULL)
         goto Cleanup;
   }

    if (!GetTokenInformation(
         hToken,         // handle to the access token
         TokenUser,    // get information about the token's groups 
         (LPVOID) ptu,   // pointer to PTOKEN_USER buffer
         dwLength,       // size of buffer
         &dwLength       // receives required buffer size
         )) 
   {
      goto Cleanup;
   }
    SID_NAME_USE SidType;
    char lpName[MAX_NAME];
    char lpDomain[MAX_NAME];

    if( !LookupAccountSid( NULL , ptu->User.Sid, lpName, &dwSize, lpDomain, &dwSize, &SidType ) )                                    
    {
        DWORD dwResult = GetLastError();
        if( dwResult == ERROR_NONE_MAPPED )
           strcpy (lpName, "NONE_MAPPED" );
        else 
        {
            printf("LookupAccountSid Error %u\n", GetLastError());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "Current user is  %s\\%s\n", 
                lpDomain, lpName );
        strUser = lpName;
        strdomain = lpDomain;
        bSuccess = TRUE;
    }

Cleanup: 

   if (ptu != NULL)
      HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, (LPVOID)ptu);
   return bSuccess;
}

HRESULT GetUserFromProcess(const DWORD procId,  _bstr_t& strUser, _bstr_t& strdomain)
{
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION,FALSE,procId); 
    if(hProcess == NULL)
        return E_FAIL;
    HANDLE hToken = NULL;

    if( !OpenProcessToken( hProcess, TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken ) )
    {
        CloseHandle( hProcess );
        return E_FAIL;
    }
    BOOL bres = GetLogonFromToken (hToken, strUser,  strdomain);

    CloseHandle( hToken );
    CloseHandle( hProcess );
    return bres?S_OK:E_FAIL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

WMI is probably the path of least resistance. You should also be able to get the token using OpenProcessToken, then GetTokenInformation to get the SID of the owner. You can then turn the SID into a user name.

Answer (score 0):

[WMI](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/processownersid.aspx) should be able to tell you that information. <s>Otherwise you need to rely on undocumented fun in ntdll.dll.</s> It appears others have found solutions that don't use ntdll.dll -- use them rather than undocumented stuff.

Comment: Undocumented stuff in ntdll.dll is undocumented for a reason.

Comment: @Stewart: I agree. That's why I didn't go into specifics.

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution knowing the process id.

```
std::optional<std::wstring> GetUserNameFromProcess(DWORD id)
{
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, id); // 1- OpenProcess
    std::wstring endUser = L"";
    std::wstring endDomain = L"";

    if (hProcess != NULL)
    {
        HANDLE  hToken = NULL;

        if (OpenProcessToken(hProcess, TOKEN_QUERY, &hToken)) // 2- OpenProcessToken
        {
            DWORD tokenSize = 0;
            GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenUser, NULL, 0, &tokenSize);

            if (tokenSize > 0)
            {
                BYTE* data = new BYTE[tokenSize];
                GetTokenInformation(hToken, TokenUser, data, tokenSize, &tokenSize); // 3- GetTokenInformation
                TOKEN_USER* pUser = (TOKEN_USER*)data;
                PSID pSID = pUser->User.Sid;
                DWORD userSize = 0;
                DWORD domainSize = 0;
                SID_NAME_USE sidName;
                LookupAccountSid(NULL, pSID, NULL, &userSize, NULL, &domainSize, &sidName);
                wchar_t* user = new wchar_t[userSize + 1];
                wchar_t* domain = new wchar_t[domainSize + 1];
                LookupAccountSid(NULL, pSID, user, &userSize, domain, &domainSize, &sidName); // 4- LookupAccountSid
                user[userSize] = L'\0';
                domain[domainSize] = L'\0';
                endUser = user;
                endDomain = domain;
                delete[] domain;
                delete[] user;
                delete[] data;
            }

            CloseHandle(hToken);
        }

        CloseHandle(hProcess);

        if (endUser != L"")
            return endUser;
    }

    return {};
}
```