# How do I find out which user started a process that is running as system

Tags: c++, windows

I've created a windows installer that runs a custom exe as part of the install & uninstall.  During the uninstall I need to find out the user name of the user that started the uninstall action.  I tried GetUserNameEx() of course, but when running from the uninstaller, it only returns the system name, not the user that invoked the action.

I presume that the information is available since using ShGetFolderPath() is able to get paths specific to the user.

Using the OpenProcessToken() and retrieving the TokenUser and TokenSource both also return only the SID of the 'system' user.

Comment: Check out this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686096/c-get-username-from-process

Comment: @millsj, Wow, I hate those multistep processes. They're so annoying when you're trying to go from point A to point B for your first time, but you have to make a stop at points C, D, and E on your way.

Comment: @chris I think that perfectly describes the entire WINAPI :)

Comment: @millsj, after jumping through those hoops, the token doesn't seem to contain the information needed.  TokenSource and TokenUser contain the same information, which is the "SYSTEM" account.