# Get the list of process for a non-admin user session in Win2K8

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get the list of all processes which are running on a user (non-admin) session. While testing the same in Windows 2008 SP2, with a non-admin user, I could find that the below piece of code fetches all the process which belongs to the that user in addition to the process running in admin user.

Is there a way to get the list of process which are running only on that user (non-admin)?

Please find the code snippet below:

```
DWORD procID = 0;
FILE *fp;

PROCESSENTRY32 processInfo;
processInfo.dwSize = sizeof(processInfo);


HANDLE processesSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);
if ( processesSnapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
{
    return;
}

fp = _tfopen(_T("C:\\Process_List.txt") , _T("a+") );

if (fp == NULL) {
   MessageBox(_T("Can't open File"));
   return;
}

Process32First(processesSnapshot, &processInfo);


_ftprintf(fp, _T("\n Process: %s :: Process ID: %d"), processInfo.szExeFile, processInfo.th32ProcessID);
procID =  processInfo.th32ProcessID;

if (procID == 0)
{
    while ( Process32Next(processesSnapshot, &processInfo) )
    {
        _ftprintf(fp, _T("\n Process: %s :: Process ID: %d"), processInfo.szExeFile, processInfo.th32ProcessID);
    }
}

fclose(fp);
CloseHandle(processesSnapshot);
```

Thanks In Advance.

regards,

Rajesh

Comment: You may need to filter the list yourself: Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686096/c-get-username-from-process