# GetTokenInformation returns invalid SID?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, winapi

While following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2686150/2990244) i ran into a problem.

```
   <DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Private Shared Function OpenProcessToken(ByVal ProcessHandle As IntPtr, ByVal DesiredAccess As Integer, ByRef TokenHandle As IntPtr) As Boolean
End Function

<DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Private Shared Function GetTokenInformation(TokenHandle As IntPtr, TokenInformationClass As TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS, TokenInformation As IntPtr, TokenInformationLength As UInteger, ByRef ReturnLength As UInteger) As Boolean
End Function

 <DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Private Shared Function IsValidSid(SID As Byte()) As Boolean
End Function


  For Each p As Process In Process.GetProcesses

        Dim processHandle As IntPtr = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, False, p.Id)
        If Not processHandle = Nothing Then
            Dim tokenhandle As IntPtr = Nothing
            Dim bool As Boolean = OpenProcessToken(processHandle, TOKEN_READ, tokenhandle)
            If bool = False Then
                Dim win32error As String = New Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error).Message

                MessageBox.Show(win32error)
            Else
                Dim sidlength As UInteger = Nothing
                Dim SIDbyte As Byte() = Nothing

                Dim somebool As Boolean = GetTokenInformation(tokenhandle, TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS.TokenUser, Nothing, 0, sidlength)

                If Not somebool Then
                    Dim win32error As String = New Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error).Message
                    MessageBox.Show(win32error)

                    ''RETURNS "The data area passed to a system call is too small" error.
                End If

                ReDim SIDbyte(35) '' I hardcoded '35' because it's what i'm getting with sidlength.

somebool = GetTokenInformation(tokenhandle, TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS.TokenUser, SIDbyte, SIDbyte.Length, sidlength)

''RETURNS TRUE THE SECOND TIME.

                If Not somebool Then
                    Dim win32error As String = New Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error).Message

                    MessageBox.Show(win32error)
                End If

                If IsValidSid(SIDbyte) Then
                    MessageBox.Show("Valid")
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Not Valid")
                End If

''RETURNS INVALID SID. (FAILS)
```

The first call to GetTokenInformation fails as it's supposed to i guess... returning "sidlength" with value of 36.
Second call succeeds and SID Byte() gets populated, but the call to "IsValidSID" Returns false... and i can't figure out why, if the SIDbytes are populated successfully, what's the problem?

Comment: You are not checking for errors. Step 1 is to add error checking.

Comment: I edited my code, please verify, it returns false the first call to GetInformationToken, returning "The data area passed to a system call is too small", setting 'sidlength' value as set above, second call it succeeds, populating 'SIDByte', but the call to IsValidSID Returns always false... any help?

Comment: If the function tells you to allocate 36 bytes, why did you allocate 35? And hard coded? Why?

Comment: Because 35 index is the 36th item since it starts at 0.
I remove'd the hardcoded part nevertheless (i was testing...), the function succeeds but the SID still doesn't appear to be valid, can't figure out why...

Comment: The declarations for GetTokenInformation and IsValidSid appear inconsistent.  Try declaring the argument to IsValidSid as an IntPtr and see if that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't did the trick, but i already found the solution, i was missing the TOKEN_USER structure and the SID_AND_ATTRIBUTES one.

Thanks anyway ;)