# How to find user name from the session ID?

Tags: c++, session, visual-c++, process, windows-xp

I have an user win32 application . That enumerates all the process details along with ProcessId. I need to print the User name along with the session ID. SessionID is enumerated using ProcessIdToSessionId() method. I want to print the User name of corresponding SessionID. This application is specially designed for WindowsXP , so the API should support WindowsXP. If anyone knows the solution please share it.

```
DWORD dwSessionId,dwPid,dwErr;
char* Uname;
ProcessIdToSessionId(dwPid,&dwSessionId);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ Get Username From Process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686096/c-get-username-from-process)

Comment: I've tried with that code but it failed in windows XP. there is any other ways to find it?

Comment: @MarshalSebastian failed how exactly? Please be more specific.

Comment: @Ari0nhh: not a duplicate.  The user running a process is not necessarily the same as the user logged into the session the process is running in.  (They're going to be the same in simple cases, but not always.)

Comment: @RemyLebeau because this application is specially designed for windows xp. the above functionality is not executing in some of our xp 32 bit laptop. i don't know why it is.

Comment: @MarshalSebastian did you debug it? Are you getting errors? Which ones exactly and on which statements? Please show the code you have tried so far.

Comment: @RemyLebeau all WTS API are failed. this issue is not common . only in some of the machines. and it does not give any error messages.

Comment: @MarshalSebastian: Again, HOW is it failing? What are the actual errors? What does your code actually look like? What is different about the systems that fail versus the systems that succeed? The WTS API has been available since Win2K, so it should work OK on all WinXP systems. I've never had a problem with it, which makes me think you are using it wrong, but you are not providing any useful details to diagnose with.

Comment: Have you checked that the "Remote Desktop Services" service is running?  (NB: it might instead be called "Terminal Services", I'm not sure when the name was first changed.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`WTSQuerySessionInformation()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383838.aspx) with the `WTSInfoClass` parameter set to [`WTSUserName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383861.aspx):

> A null-terminated string that contains the name of the user associated with the session.

Comment: [WTSQuerySessionInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383838.aspx) is also used this method is not supporting in some of our windows xp 32 bit laptops. That's why i asked about alternative solution.

Comment: @MarshalSebastian then you should have stated that up front, and explained how it is not working for you.