# How to kill my own process without killing same process of another user

Tags: c++, windows

Working Environment: Windows, C++

I am running `xx.exe`, and another user(user B) is running `xx.exe` at the same time. I want to kill my own `xx.exe` process programatically. When I used `TIhelp32.h` functions to kill `xx.exe`, it also kills user B's `xx.exe` too.

I do not have an admin's privileges. How can I kill my own process programatically?

Comment: What about just calling [`std::exit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit) or [`std::terminate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate)?

Comment: I think this might be what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686096/c-get-username-from-process. You can check the user before terminating the process.

Comment: `return` from `main()`.

Comment: I suspect this question is not programming and would be a better fit for superuser.com

Comment: Judging from the comments, you should probably clarify that you want to kill `xx.exe` from another process, not from within itself.

Comment: If it's your "xx.exe" process, as in spawned by your process, then you should have an all-access handle for it, as returned by `CreateProcessW` or `ShellExecuteExW` (with the flag `SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS`). You can terminate it forcefully via `TerminateProcess`. Or you can get its process ID via `GetProcessId`; enumerate top-level windows via `EnumWindows`; send `WM_CLOSE` to all of its windows as determined by `GetWindowThreadProcessId`; wait on the handle via `WaitForSingleObject` for a few seconds in order for it to exit on its own; and then terminate it if it's still running.