# Finding active application for every logged on user

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I need help with Windows API, I need to implement an windows app, that for every logged-in user records what application is currently in focus (active) and log that information in txt file. Since im not so good with Windows API, can someone help me at least with some guidelines how to do that, what Windows OS methods to use for that, etc? Thank you

EDIT: Im having hard time finding a way to see what application is in focus by each user. Im using LsaEnumerateLogonSessions to find list of all logged-in users, and than LsaGetLogonSessionData to get information about user, but thats all that i have for now.

Comment: [WinEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/winevents-infrastructure).

Comment: Look at the edit. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is no API to query the active app in another session.

You will have to run a process inside each session via `CreateProcessAsUser()`, where that process calls `GetForegroundWindow()` to get the session's active focused window, and then query that window for info, such as its caption via `GetWindowText()`, or its owning EXE's filename via   `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` + `OpenProcess()` + `GetModuleFileNameEx()`, etc, and then communicate that info back to your main app via any IPC mechanism you want that can cross session boundaries (pipes, sockets, etc).

Comment: I was thinking about that, but the problem is, i dont have password for other users, and in order to call CreatProcessAsUser, i need to call LogonUser with users passwrod. Is there any way to do that without password?

Comment: Hello @Remy Lebau. I managed to use WTSEnumerateSessionsA to get all sessions, than to WTSQueryUserToken to use it for CreateProcessAsUser. But im not sure how to call GetForegroundWindow() with it, since CreateProcessAsUser only accepts exe files? Could you give me a little code example?

Comment: @MrDejan995 you would have to make another EXE program to do the work of getting the window info and communicating it back. Or you can just launch a 2nd copy of your main EXE, giving it input parameters to tell its WinMain to just do the extra work and then exit, instead of doing its main code.

Answer (score 0):

Run your application **as administrator** with calling [**EnumProcesses**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-enumprocesses) function to enumerate the current processes (of **different users**) in the system.

Use [GetModuleBaseName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getmodulebasenamea) to get process/application name.

Refer to [Enumerating All Processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/psapi/enumerating-all-processes) for more detailed information.

If you want to check user name refer to this thread: [C++ Get Username From Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686096/c-get-username-from-process).