# Convert SessionId to User Account SID _without_ WTSQuerySessionInformation?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, windows-10, windows-identity

I'm working on a service (C#) that receives session-change notifications (specifically SessionLogon). The only piece of information I get with that notification is `SessionId`.

My ultimate goal is to check the logon user's profile (local/roaming AppData/MyCorp/MyApp folder) for a particular setting, and perform a task if it's there.

I need to go from **SessionId** to something I can map to a local user profile, either directly to a **User Account SID** or to something that can be mapped to a SID, (e.g. **"<domain>\<username>"**, etc).

The solutions I've found on SO depend upon Windows Terminal Services (WTS) APIs (e.g. [`WTSQuerySessionInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wtsapi32/nf-wtsapi32-wtsquerysessioninformationw)), but *Remote Desktop Services isn't available on Windows 10 Home edition*, so that's a non-starter.

Does anyone know how to map from **SessionId** to a local user account that doesn't involve WTS APIs?

## (EDIT #1) CLARIFICATION:

In .NET, the ServiceBase class has an `OnSessionChange` override that gets called for login/logout/unlock/lock events. I was originally thinking this was for *all* such events (from physical machine or Terminal Server).

It looks like this *only* applies to Terminal Server sessions(?) So, apparently, the `sessionId` that I get back is a TerminalServer-specific thing. As @RbMm points out below, this override probably wouldn't get called in the first place on Windows Home edition. It's a moot point, though, because it was the local (physical) logon events I was interested in, and that's completely different from Terminal Service sessions.

It seems odd to me that the service base class would have a useful event like this, but have it tied to *Terminal Services*, rather than work for all cases. Maybe someone has some insight into this?

## (EDIT #2) REALIZATION:

@RbMm's comments have cleared up some misconceptions that I started with. Here's a update:

- The OnSessionChange event is *only* for Terminal Services, and has nothing to do with local (physical) logon sessions (I was conflating the two).
- I'm *only* interested in the local logon sessions, so I'll be looking for a way to get notified about *them* inside my service. If no such notification is available, I'll have to set up a timer and poll.
- I'll need to derive a user account SID from whatever piece of information I receive along with such a notification (or periodic call to `LsaGetLogonSessionData`)

Comment: Are you saying you have tried callign the WTS apis and they dont exist, or they dont work?

Comment: @MichaelRandall - The API mentioned above  is documented (updated w/link) **not to work** if Remote Desktop Services isn't running. Windows 10 Home editions reportedly don't include remote desktop at all. I haven't actually **tried** it, but that's why I believe it won't work...

Comment: Yeah maybe so, anyway, where does it say this calls fails on windows home or when the service is not running? edit ahh i see now

Comment: I am wondering if you can the user from the session id via WMI

Comment: @ScottSmith Find a process running in the given session (maybe enumerate and match [`ProcessIdToSessionId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-processidtosessionid)) then [lookup SID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2686150).

Comment: *I haven't actually tried it, but that's why I believe it won't work* - why not at begin try call `WTSQuerySessionInformationW` before ask ?

Comment: if Remote Desktop Services isn't available or not running - simply will be no session change. as result no notifications, and you never call `WTSQuerySessionInformationW` in this case. from another side this api is exported always so you always can import it

Comment: @RbMm - "why not at begin try call WTSQuerySessionInformationW before ask ?" Normally I would, but I'd have to write the code, spin up a WIndows Home instance, install the service and test it. Probably at least a day's work for something that's documented _not_ to work.

Comment: @ScottSmith - read my next comment

Comment: @RbMm - I've updated the question with some clarifications based on your feedback

Comment: also i think documentation is very bad and incorrect. *If Remote Desktop Services is not running, calls to WTSQuerySessionInformation fail* - unclear this is only for *To retrieve the session ID* or for any case. but on my system Remote Desktop Services (*TermService*) is not running, but `WTSQuerySessionInformation` is **not fail** and return actual info

Comment: `OnSessionChange` - how i understand you register exactly terminal session notifications. not logon sessions. here you get `wParam` parameter of the [`WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/wm-wtssession-change) message and pointer to [`WTSSESSION_NOTIFICATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-wtssession_notification). so you need call exactly `WTSQuerySessionInformationW(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, dwSessionId, WTSSessionInfo, (PWSTR*)&pp, &dwSessionId)` and i sure this call not fail.

Comment: i think you not understand different between terminal and logon sessions..inside single terminal session can be several different logon sessions. run for example [this](https://github.com/rbmm/partial/blob/master/X64/lgSessions.exe) an look output

Comment: anyway service when registered for `SERVICE_ACCEPT_SESSIONCHANGE` it got [`SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nc-winsvc-lphandler_function_ex) notifications. it called when user logon, logoff, lock, unlock.. etc. local user too, not only for remote. in case local user `WinStationName` will be *Console*

Answer (score 1):

I think you can retrieve this information via WMI

[Win32_LogonSession](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-logonsession)

```
class Win32_LogonSession : Win32_Session
{
  string   Caption;
  string   Description;
  datetime InstallDate;
  string   Name;
  string   Status;
  datetime StartTime;
  string   AuthenticationPackage;
  string   LogonId;
  uint32   LogonType;
};
```

Furthermore:

> **LogonId**
>
> Data type: string
>
> Access type: Read-only
>
> Qualifiers: key
>
> ID assigned to the logon session.

**Example**

```
var scope = new ManagementScope(ManagementPath.DefaultPath);
var query = new SelectQuery($"Select * from Win32_LogonSession where LogonId = {SessionId}");
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
var results = searcher.Get();
foreach (ManagementObject mo in results)
{
 
}
```

Note this is fully untested

Comment: question about **logon** sessions (*LUID*) or **terminal** sessions (*ULONG*) ? this is absolute different things. you query information about logon session. for this exist [*LsaGetLogonSessionData*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ntsecapi/nf-ntsecapi-lsagetlogonsessiondata). use wmi always bad solution. this is only remote call to wmi service process. but what api then this process call for get info ? why not call this api direct ?

Comment: @RbMm if  LsaGetLogonSessionData does what the OP wants. Maybe you can answer this question :) my answer was only a guess, if its wrong, ill happily delte

Comment: i not understand original question - about which session he ask. but i simply note - if information can get with wmi - this mean the same information we can get without wmi (this is only very slow remote call). in all sense better use `LsaGetLogonSessionData` which return [`SECURITY_LOGON_SESSION_DATA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ntsecapi/ns-ntsecapi-security_logon_session_data) then wmi which internal anyway call `LsaGetLogonSessionData`

Comment: @RbMm ahh ok, i understand what you are saying. Yes `WMI` is slow and should be discouraged. The OP has a session ID, he will have to try and get the `LogonId` from the `SessionId` to use this method (`LsaGetLogonSessionData`), i am not sure how this can be done.

Comment: LogonId and SessionId absolute different. in same SessionId can be multiple different LogonId sessions. i think OP ask about terminal session id which he received inside [`HandlerEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nc-winsvc-lphandler_function_ex) - `SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE` and [`WTSSESSION_NOTIFICATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-wtssession_notification). where he got `DWORD dwSessionId`. you , i assume, confuse this with logon sessions

Comment: @RbMm yeah, its true, and it makes sense now that you say it. Maybe you can write an answer explaining ? ill delete this answer

Comment: sorry for delay, but i think [*this comment*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63387067/convert-sessionid-to-user-account-sid-without-wtsquerysessioninformation/63387677?noredirect=1#comment112089423_63387067) explain situation

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve this info via processes instead of tokens.
I dont have a c# sample here, but here is PS-snippet to demo the concept:

```
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devnotes/getting-the-active-console-session-id
$sessionId = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReadByte(0x7ffe02d8)
$pList = (Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "name = 'explorer.exe' and SessionId=$sessionId")
$winEx = $pList | where {$_.Path -eq 'C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe'} | sort CreationDate | select -First 1
$sid = (Invoke-CimMethod -InputObject $winEx -MethodName GetOwnerSid).sid
```