# How to get process SID from its handle?

Tags: c, winapi, handle, sid

Consider I have the following handle for process:

```
HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, entry.th32ProcessID);
```

How can I get process's SID? It's necessary as I need to give permission for this process to some file. I thought that maybe `GetSecurityInfo()` might help, however I have no idea how to use it for process. To be more specific, I don't know how to specify `SE_OBJECT_TYPE` (2nd parameter).

Comment: SID is relevant to a user or group, not a process.  Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686096/c-get-username-from-process).

Comment: So there is no way to make file accesible for certain processes? @HansPassant

Comment: @szefitoo No. Windows' security is based on users/groups, not on processes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to make file accesible ONLY for certain processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73055463/is-it-possible-to-make-file-accesible-only-for-certain-processes) - this question was the first attempt, the linked one is the second, to basically the same issue of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Doc: [SID structure (winnt.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-sid)

> The security identifier (SID) structure is a variable-length structure
> used to uniquely identify users or groups.

As far as I'm concerned, you couldn't get process's SID.