# WMI IWbemServices::ExecMethod is slow on Win32API

Tags: c++, winapi, process, wmi

I am trying to get info for all running processes on windows. Through ExecMethod I am trying to get user name and domain of a process owner. I am doing it like this:

```
 HRESULT hres;
    BSTR MethodName = SysAllocString(L"GetOwner");
    BSTR ClassName = SysAllocString(L"Win32_Process");

    // get the object containing our desired method
    IWbemClassObject* pClass = NULL;
    hres = m_pSvc->GetObject(ClassName, 0, NULL, &pClass, NULL);
    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        printf("GetObject hres = %08x\n", hres);

    }

    // get the desired method
    // in our case, we only need pmethodGetOwner since GetOwner really only has output
    IWbemClassObject* pMethod_GetOwner = NULL;
    hres = pClass->GetMethod(MethodName, 0, NULL, &pMethod_GetOwner);
    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        printf("GetMethod hres = %08x\n", hres);
    }

    // spawn the instance of the method
    IWbemClassObject* pInInst = NULL;
    hres = pMethod_GetOwner->SpawnInstance(0, &pInInst);
    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        printf("SpawnInstance hres = %08x\n", hres);
    }


    IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = NULL;
    BSTR wql = SysAllocString(L"WQL");
    BSTR query = SysAllocString(L"SELECT * FROM Win32_Process");
    hres = m_pSvc->ExecQuery( wql, query,
                           WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, NULL, &pEnumerator);
    SysReleaseString(wql);
    SysReleaseString(query);
    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        qDebug() << "ExecQuery failed" << " Error code = 0x"    << std::hex << hres << '\n';
        qDebug()<< _com_error(hres).ErrorMessage() << '\n';
        return std::vector<DCProcessInfo>();            // Program has failed.
    }

    // Get the data from the WQL sentence
    IWbemClassObject *pclsObj = NULL;
    ULONG uReturn = 0;
    std::vector<DCProcessInfo> process_list{};
    double seconds{};
    while (pEnumerator)
    {
        DCProcessInfo proc_info;
        HRESULT hr = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &pclsObj, &uReturn);

        if(0 == uReturn || FAILED(hr))
            break;

        VARIANT vtProp;
        hr = pclsObj->Get(L"Name",0,&vtProp,NULL,NULL);
        if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
            proc_info.name = QString::fromWCharArray(vtProp.bstrVal);
        VariantClear(&vtProp);

        hr = pclsObj->Get(L"ProcessId",0,&vtProp,NULL,NULL);
        if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
            proc_info.pid = vtProp.uintVal;
        VariantClear(&vtProp);

        hr = pclsObj->Get(L"CreationDate",0,&vtProp,NULL,NULL);
        if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
            proc_info.creation_date = tools::fromBSTRToDateTime(vtProp.bstrVal);
        VariantClear(&vtProp);

        hr = pclsObj->Get(L"ExecutablePath",0,&vtProp,NULL,NULL);
        if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
            proc_info.file_path = QString::fromWCharArray(vtProp.bstrVal);
        VariantClear(&vtProp);

        hr = pclsObj->Get(L"CommandLine",0,&vtProp,NULL,NULL);
        if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
            proc_info.command_line = QString::fromWCharArray(vtProp.bstrVal);
        VariantClear(&vtProp);

//        std::pair<QString,QString> user_domain = get_process_user_domain(pclsObj);
//        proc_info.owner_user = user_domain.first;
//        proc_info.owner_domain = user_domain.second;

        VARIANT vtVal;
        std::pair<QString,QString> user_dom{};

        hr =pclsObj->Get(L"__PATH",0,&vtVal,0,0);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            qDebug()<<"get_process_user_domain() failed Get(__PATH)";
            pClass->Release();
            pMethod_GetOwner->Release();
            pInInst->Release();
            //return user_dom;
        }
        std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        hr = m_pSvc->ExecMethod(vtVal.bstrVal, MethodName, 0, NULL, NULL, &pMethod_GetOwner, NULL);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            qDebug()<<"get_process_user_domain() failed ExecMethod against" << QString::fromWCharArray(V_BSTR(&vtVal));;
            pclsObj->Release();
            continue;
        }
        VariantClear(&vtVal);
        auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end-start;
        qDebug()<<elapsed_seconds.count();
        hr = pMethod_GetOwner->Get(L"User", 0, &vtVal, NULL, 0);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            qDebug()<<"get_process_user_domain() failed Get(User)";
            pClass->Release();
            pMethod_GetOwner->Release();
            pInInst->Release();
            //return user_dom;
        }
        else
            proc_info.owner_user = QString::fromWCharArray(vtVal.bstrVal);

        VariantClear(&vtVal);
        hr = pMethod_GetOwner->Get(L"Domain", 0, &vtVal, NULL, 0);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            qDebug()<<"get_process_user_domain() failed Get(Domain)";
            //return user_dom;
        }
        else
            proc_info.owner_domain = QString::fromWCharArray(vtVal.bstrVal);

        VariantClear(&vtVal);

        process_list.push_back(proc_info);
        pclsObj->Release();
        pclsObj=NULL;
    }


    qDebug()<<"time passed:"<<seconds;
    pClass->Release();
    pMethod_GetOwner->Release();
    pInInst->Release();
    return process_list;
```

The problem is that ExecMethod is very slow (around 0.2 sec per call, which is very slow when you calling it like 200 times). I want to ask maybe I am doing something wrong or is it supposed to be that slow? If it supposed to be that slow, are there any alternatives?

I've tried to enumerate my processes through CreateToolhelp32Snapshot, but it doesn't have enough info. So WMI was a good(and relatively fast) solution before I tried to call GetOwner method.

Comment: But it works. In addition, [the process token contains information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-gettokeninformation) you want. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8992043/15511041

Comment: Probably you need a [Asynchronous Mode or Semisynchronous Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/calling-a-method) call.

Comment: Token method works well for me. I didn't know I can retrieve info that way, I am a newbie in win api... Thank you.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT Can you post your response as an answer, so I can mark it as a solution? Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76063861/wmi-iwbemservicesexecmethod-is-slow-on-win32api?noredirect=1#comment134157227_76063861) said, [the process token contains information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-gettokeninformation) you want. With [TokenUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ne-winnt-token_information_class), you will receive a [TOKEN_USER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnt/ns-winnt-token_user) structure that contains the user account of the token. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8992043/15511041) for a code example.